# Vim turn on syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I've been using Vim as my text editor, but now that I'm using it to write Python code, I'd like it to hightlight the syntax like this:

[image]

How do I turn on syntax highlighting in Vim? How do I get it to stay on by default for programming files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Turning On Syntax Highlighting:

1. Open the file that you'd like to have syntax highlighting enabled for with `vim filename.py`.
2. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>, then type `:syntax on` and hit enter.
3. Syntax highlighting should now be enabled!
   [image]

Note: This will only turn on syntax highlighting temporarily. In other words, if you quit working on that file and open it again, or open a different file with vim, syntax highlighting will be off by default. If you'd like to make syntax highlighting permanent, you need to do some extra steps.

## Enabling Syntax Highlighting by Default:

1. Change directory to your home directory by typing `cd` into the terminal.
2. Type `vim .vimrc`, which will edit the *.vimrc* file if you have it, or create it if you don't.
   [image]
3. Append `syntax on` to the file as a new line, then hit <kbd>esc</kbd>, type `:wq`, and hit enter. 
   [image]

Syntax highlighting will now be enabled by default for files ending in common programming language extensions such as `.py`.

If you would like to turn off the syntax highlighting for a particular file, you can do that on a case by case basis.

## Turning Off Syntax Highlighting for a Specific File:

1. Open the file that you'd like to have synta highlighting disabled for with `vim filename.py`.
2. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>, then type `:syntax off` and hit enter.
3. Syntax highlighting should now be disabled!